# Render view with js.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I have, for example, index.html.erb I can create javascript file for it - index.js.erb.

How can i create JS file for partial like _profile_list.html.erb, rendered in view?

Comment: why you want to make js file for partial ?

Answer (score 0):

In the targeting template (index.html.erb) you could add this line:

```
<%= yield :js %>
```

Then in the partial (_profile_list.html.erb):

```
<% content_for :js do %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "some-javascript" %>
<% end %>
```